# java library to run shell commands on multiple remote machines simultaneously

Tags: java, shell, remote-server

For example, I have instantiated 3 virtual machines in Amazon EC2-- I have also uploaded 3 different shell scripts to each of those machines... Now, I want to execute each of those 3 scripts... I know that each script will take some time to complete, so I want to start all 3 scripts together, and then wait for each of them to be complete...How do I do this? Is there a way to do this without using threads?

Comment: What exactly is wrong with using threads?

Comment: @smcg i may be required to do the above for many machines, eg for 500 virtual machines... that is why i am looking for a solution that does not use threads-- viz threaded processes performance depends upon no.of CPU cores-- and I dont have a machine with (for eg) 500 cores :(

Comment: you can execute more threads than you have CPU cores, it will just be slower. One core can execute multiple threads. But regardless, a Java library is not what you want to use for this job. You should be using some configuration management software such as Chef or Puppet.